# Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Tags: javascript, api, maps

Please can someone point me in the right direction.

I have spent a few days watching videos and reading up on google maps and am more confused now than when I started.

I run a worpress site and want to add a google map to show venues. I have done this by copying the the html from a previous google map that I created. I decided to start afresh and try to style the map that it looks more attractive and also see if I could create a database with my site locations that I could update.

In the process I came across a pluging that asked me for my API key. I struggled to find my API key and then started reading that google maps has done away with its previous version and is now using something called Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

Please can someone guide me how to go about using this and what its all about. I've read up on [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Audience) but am still confused. ?

If someone has some useful videos, like idiots guide to getting started....

Comment: Here's a link to the [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) for the latest version of Google Maps.

On the side bar in there you'll see that there are links to [code samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/) and [demos](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery).  These should explain to you the basics of using the API to generate a map.

Answer (score 0):

The basic documentation can be found at [google's developers site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference). If you are struggling with the basic maps functionality and skinning, you may find it helpful to use a wrapper that simplifies a lot of the process, like [this gmaps project on github](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/).

If you have a more specific problem, maybe you could edit your post and list exactly what hurdles you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wordpress, why not try a plugin directly? It would probably take care of all the specifics, and leave you with just having to deal with managing the site. This one has rather good ratings:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/

Regarding your API key, it's something Google gives you when you register your site in order to use Maps. Try re registering.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/getting-creative-with-the-google-maps-api/.  Kind of like a beginners guide...